# npm package is not listed in project's package.json but no extraneous error

Tags: node.js, npm

I see a weird situation in my project.
There are 3 packages not listed in `package.json`, but installed during the development process.

In my understanding, `npm list` should show me `extraneous error`. However, no error displayed. I am wondering how npm decides which package is extraneous or not?

The three packages are `async`, `debug` and `mime`. and I am using the `npm 1.4.28`

Comment: What does "installed during the development process." mean?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure when I install them, it might be `npm install async` or `npm install async --save` or `npm install async --save-dev` However, I've just noticed that if I uninstall them, npm list will show me error that they are required by the packages, e.g. I just see npm ERR! missing: debug@*, required by mocha@1.18.2 . It seems it was not installed by me, it was installed because I install mocha.

Comment: I am sorry that I want to close this question, because I've tried to uninstall the packages which is not listed in my package.json, and I see immediately some errors, e.g. `npm ERR! missing: debug@*, required by mocha@1.18.2` . Then, I reinstall the packages required in these error, and they are gone.

So, I guess it is because these packages was installed by me temporally during development, and they become `required` when I install other packages, and not extraneous any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should update your `npm`, since `1.4.28` is quite old; latest is `2.4.1`.

Secondly, a package is only extraneous if it is not a (dependency, devDependency, optionalDependency) named in `package.json` **or any of its dependencies**.

For example, I can create this scenario:

`$ mkdir test && cd test
$ echo {} > package.json
$ npm install --save jslint
$ npm install exit
$ npm ls`

Now `exit` is extraneous, even though it is a dependency of `jslint`, because `jslint` has its own version of `exit` under `node_modules/jslint/node_modules/exit`.  Let's get rid of that:

`$ rm -rf node_modules/jslint/node_module/exit
$ npm ls`

Now `exit` is no longer extraneous because it is needed to fulfill the dependency of `jslint`.  But if I look in `./node_modules` I will see two packages, `exit` and `jslint`, only one of which is named in `package.json`.

Please let me know if I have misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean in my comments, in which I want to close the question after I understand this. Your demonstration is more clear to explain what exactly the extraneous is. Thank you :)

Comment: Additional comment. I think the npm extraneous question is not about npm version 1.4.28 :)

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering how npm decides which package is extraneous or not?

Installed package that is not in package.json will trigger `npm extraneous error`.

Try to refresh local `node_modules` directory.
Install needed packages with `--save`/`--save-dev` key.

Comment: Your answer is my question. `Installed package that is not in package.json should trigger npm extraneous error`. However, in my case, it doesn't trigger this error. In addition, when I uninstalled this packages which is not listed in package.json. `npm list` will show me errors, e.g. `npm ERR! missing: debug@*, required by mocha@1.18.2`

So, I am sorry `Installed package that is not in package.json will trigger npm extraneous error.` is not a correct answer, and I guess npm has its own logic to decide which package is extraneous or not.